# Is there a way to recognize blank lines in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, text-files

Is there a way to recognize blank lines when you are scanning a text file in Matlab? I want to parse the files based on the blank lines in between the text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. A MATLAB snippet would look something like:

```
fid = fopen('reader.m');

newline = sprintf('\r\n');
line = fgets(fid);
while ischar(line)
    if strcmp(newline, line)
        disp('Empty line');
    else
        disp('Non-empty line');
    end
    line = fgets(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
lines = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);
lines = lines{1};
% lines now contains a cell array of strings,
% one per line in the file.

% Find all the blank lines using cellfun:
blank_lines = find(cellfun('isempty', lines));
```

Comment: It works with comments as well:`lines = textscan(fid, '%s', 'CommentStyle', '#')`

Answer (score 0):

without \r...now works fine

```
fid = fopen('reader.m');

newline = sprintf('\n');
line = fgets(fid);
while ischar(line)
    if strcmp(newline, line)
        disp('Empty line');
    else
        disp('Non-empty line');
    end
    line = fgets(fid);
end
```